# Accessing Rational DOORS database

Tags: url, ibm-doors

I need to control Rational DOORS client from a custom application (in java, if that matters).

Requirement is very simple: to open the DOORS client pointing to a specific requirement (as specified by its tag). DOORS client can then remain open or be closed independently from my app.

I do not really know DOORS and neither use it for my daily work, so my competence is very limited.

Ideal would be to build a URL containing the query to point directly to the needed element. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Every requirement in DOORS has a URL. The URL format is

```
doors://<Server>:<Port>/ ?.............
```

The URL can be fetched by opening the properties of the requirement. To make things easy, A DOORS manager can provide an export the Requirement-ID against the URL in an Excel.